# How can I prevent duplicated executing tests about Suite in JUnit4?

Tags: java, testing, junit, test-suite, suite

We are using Java 8 and Junit version 4.13.2, and we want to bundle the following two tests into a TestSuite to test them.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class ATest {

  // Some tests..

}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class BTest {

  // Some tests..

}
```

This is TestSuite class.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ATest.class, BTest.class})
public class ABSuite {
}
```

There is no problem executing tests for the `ABSuite` class. However, when running "run all tests" in IntelliJ or running `mvn clean test`, all methods of both `ATest` and `BTest` classes as well as `ABSuite` are executed twice, resulting in duplicate execution of each test class.

['run all tests' button in intellij'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7BzS.png)

While adding `<excludedGroups>com.sov.example.BTest,com.sov.example.BTest</excludedGroups>` to the `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration in `pom.xml` works when running `mvn clean test`, I would like to seek advice on how to prevent duplicate execution of the test classes when running "run all tests" in the IDE. Thank you

Comment: what is `All Tests` here?

Comment: @AshishPatil It means that executing all test of a module in intellij IDE. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7BzS.png )

Comment: I don't think you can prevent it. This is like "select all". You can however select in IDE only the suite (or multiple suites holding Ctrl) and run them.